# SQLAlchemy: select over multiple tables

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I wanted to optimize my database query:

```
link_list = select(
    columns=[link_table.c.rating, link_table.c.url, link_table.c.donations_in],
    whereclause=and_(
        not_(link_table.c.id.in_(
            select(
                columns=[request_table.c.recipient],
                whereclause=request_table.c.donator==donator.id
            ).as_scalar()
        )),
        link_table.c.id!=donator.id,
    ),
    limit=20,
).execute().fetchall()
```

and tried to merge those two selects in one query:

```
link_list = select(
    columns=[link_table.c.rating, link_table.c.url, link_table.c.donations_in],
    whereclause=and_(
        link_table.c.active==True,
        link_table.c.id!=donator.id,
        request_table.c.donator==donator.id,
        link_table.c.id!=request_table.c.recipient,
    ),
    limit=20,
    order_by=[link_table.c.rating.desc()]
).execute().fetchall()
```

the database-schema looks like:

```
link_table = Table('links', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column('url', Unicode(250), index=True, unique=True),
    Column('registration_date', DateTime),
    Column('donations_in', Integer),
    Column('active', Boolean),
)
request_table = Table('requests', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column('recipient', Integer, ForeignKey('links.id')),
    Column('donator', Integer, ForeignKey('links.id')),
    Column('date', DateTime),
)
```

There are several links (donator) in request_table pointing to one link in the link_table. I want to have links from link_table, which are not yet "requested".

But this does not work. Is it actually possible, what I'm trying to do? If so, how would you do that?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I solved this issue my own. I needed an left outer join, because it is a many-to-one relation.

Thanks!

Comment: @ahojnnes: Please post your solution in the answers, for history purposes.

Comment: to be honest my solution was no solution, because in the end I realized that it did something different. But at the moment I reached a point, where I think this is not possible with joins - at least not as efficient as with the two select's.

So I would be still glad about an answer!

Comment: It will be much easier to help you if you post the actual queries themselves, instead of this (sqlalchemy?) code that is generating some query.

Answer (score 1):

You may be look for the SQL `NOT EXISTS` construct:

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/tutorial.html#using-exists

Answer (score 0):

Riffing on [masida's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061154/sqlalchemy-select-over-multiple-tables/6901455#6901455):

First, the original query:

```
>>> print select(
...     columns=[link_table.c.url, link_table.c.donations_in],
...     whereclause=and_(
...         not_(link_table.c.id.in_(
...             select(
...                 columns=[request_table.c.recipient],
...                 whereclause=request_table.c.donator==5
...             ).as_scalar()
...         )),
...         link_table.c.id!=5,
...     ),
...     limit=20,
... )
SELECT links.url, links.donations_in 
FROM links 
WHERE links.id NOT IN (SELECT requests.recipient 
FROM requests 
WHERE requests.donator = :donator_1) AND links.id != :id_1 
 LIMIT 20
```

And rewritten in terms of exists():

```
>>> print select(
...     columns=[link_table.c.url, link_table.c.donations_in],
...     whereclause=and_(
...     not_(exists().where(request_table.c.donator==5)),
...     #    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...         link_table.c.id!=5,
...     ),
...     limit=20,
... )
SELECT links.url, links.donations_in 
FROM links 
WHERE NOT (EXISTS (SELECT * 
FROM requests 
WHERE requests.donator = :donator_1)) AND links.id != :id_1 
 LIMIT 20
```

Comment: this kind of rewrite makes sense on MySQL, which is notorious for poorly optimizing subselects;  Other DBMSes may not benefit at all; for instance postgresql will always plan a "not in subselect" as an anti-join, in exactly the same way as it plans "not exists"